# Tkinter Buttons Created in a for loops but can't reference data

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter project i'm working on. The end goal is to have a Window appear that has all of the data in a json file appear as individual objects (either a button or next to a button) that can then be clicked to have the data altered and saved back to the json file as well as an option to add new levels.

What makes this complicated is that because I'm making it "future proof", i have to create the buttons in a loop, so their names are not defined for me to reference later. I've tried using cget(), passing them through a validation in tkinter, v.focus_get(), and none of them come up correct. For a second i thought that .grid() being on the same line might make me reference the grid object, while not wrong, changing that did not fix the issue. Using cget() gave me "." as whatever information i try to pull.

I'm not married to my formatting, it can be a pop up window, through text boxes, i just don't want to put it all in a listbox with all of the information where someone could then mess up the json formatting
I will simplify the data in the json file and code below.

```
{
    "fabrication_cost": 17,
    "mark_up": 0.7,
    "stone_levels": {
        "granite1": {
            "Name": "Granite Level 1",
            "Colors": [
                "Azul Platino",
                "Blanco Tulum",
                "Caledonia",
                "Luna Pearl"
            ],
            "Price": 7.5
        },
        "granite2": {
            "Name": "Granite Level 2",
            "Colors": [
                "Fantasy Brown",
                "Gray Mist",
                "Santa Cecilia",
                "New Venetian Gold"
            ],
            "Price": 10
        },
        "granite3": {
            "Name": "Granite Level 3",
            "Colors": [
                "Nero Mist Honed",
                "Salinas White",
                "Steel Grey Polished",
                "Steel Grey Brushed"
            ],
            "Price": 12
        },
        "quartz1": {
            "Name": "Quartz Level 1",
            "Colors": [
                "Frost White",
                "Iced White",
                "Manhattan Gray",
                "Peppercorn White"
            ],
            "Price": 17
        },
        "quartz2": {
            "Name": "Quartz Level 2",
            "Colors": [
                "Carrara Grigio",
                "Carrara Mist",
                "Fossil Gray",
                "Midnight Majesty"
            ],
            "Price": 22.5
        },
        "quartz3": {
            "Name": "Quartz Level 3",
            "Colors": [
                "Babylon Gray",
                "Calacatta Classique",
                "Calacatta Vicenza",
                "Gray Lagoon"
            ],
            "Price": 25.5
        }
    },
    "edge_pricing": {
        "Roundover/Bevel": 8,
        "Half Bullnose": 10,
        "Full Bullnose": 15,
        "Ogee": 30,
        "Mitered": 50
    },
    "add_ons": {
        "trip_Charge": 250,
        "raw_Cutout": 50,
        "radii": 50,
        "arcs": 100,
        "splay": 100,
        "waterfall": 650,
        "farm_sink_cutout": 100,
        "undermount_Sink_Install": 100,
        "standard_18ga_Sink": 110,
        "upgrade_18ga_Sink": 240,
        "porcelain_Vanity_Sink": 45,
        "customer_Sink": 100
    }
}
```

```
import json
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        #load data from json file
        with open("pricing_data.json","r") as pricing_data_json:
            pricing_data = json.load(pricing_data_json)
        self.stone_levels = pricing_data['stone_levels']

        #create main frame
        self.main_frame = tk.Frame()
        self.main_frame.grid(row=0,column=0)

        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        r=0
        for granite_level in self.stone_levels:

            lvl_name = self.stone_levels[granite_level]['Name']
            
            lvl_colors = self.stone_levels[granite_level]['Colors']

            tk.Button(master=self.main_frame, text=lvl_name).grid(row=r, column=0, sticky='news')
            tk.Button(master=self.main_frame, text=lvl_colors).grid(row=r+1, column=0, sticky='news')
            tk.Button(master=self.main_frame,text='Add New Level').grid(row=r+2, column=0)
            r+=3

app= App()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"For a second i thought that .grid() being on the same line might make me reference the grid object, while not wrong"_ - actually, that statement is wrong. There is no "grid object". Calling `grid` returns `None`.

Comment: You haven't assigned a command to the buttons, so it's not clear how you're expecting to get the data associated with a button. Also, when I run this code with this data I get an error: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`.

Comment: @BryanOakley my terminology was incorrect. In using "object" i meant that calling .grid() returns none but didn't have a better noun to call .grid()
I'm going to load the json file again.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes there are currently no commands because I can't even get the buttons to do anyhting. When they buttons are created the data info is put in as text to show which button should correspond with which data, but I can't make the button reference any data after its been created because there's no references to the button itself (created in a loop with no name). Even forcing a name with f-strings won't let me reference them. Something like name = f'{level_colors}{r}'

Comment: I can create a function, but i don't even know what to make it do, i'm completely at a loss. The button on click, should open some form of 'editor' for the info seen as text on the button, but i don't know how to pull the data after the button is created

Answer (score 0):

Solved: The over arching problem was that I could not reference buttons without naming them, and using the inbuilt name function in tkinter does not allow referencing. I had to create a class for the buttons, use tk.IntVar() to name the buttons.

```
import json
import tkinter as tk

#make buttons
class GregButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, window, name="", *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = tk.IntVar()
        self.name.set(name)
        super(GregButton, self).__init__(
            window, *args, textvariable=self.name, command=self.button_do, **kwargs
        )

    def button_do(self):
        print("hello")
        # Top level window
        frame = tk.Tk()
        frame.title("TextBox Input")
        frame.geometry("400x200")
        # Function for getting Input
        # from textbox and printing it
        # at label widget

        def printInput():
            inp = inputtxt.get(1.0, "end-1c")
            lbl.config(text="Provided Input: " + inp)
            self.name.set(inp)

        # TextBox Creation
        inputtxt = tk.Text(frame, height=5, width=20)

        inputtxt.pack()

        # Button Creation
        printButton = tk.Button(frame, text="Print", command=printInput)
        printButton.pack()

        # Label Creation
        lbl = tk.Label(frame, text="")
        lbl.pack()
        frame.mainloop()


# load data from json file
with open("pricing_data.json", "r") as pricing_data_json:
    pricing_data = json.load(pricing_data_json)

#levels
stone_levels = pricing_data["stone_levels"]
#window no frame
window = tk.Tk()
#lsit of buttons for later?
btns = []
#make and add buttons to list
for granite_level in stone_levels:
    btns.append(GregButton(window, stone_levels[granite_level]["Name"]))
#pack buttons onto window
for btn in btns:
    btn.pack()
window.mainloop()
```